# Cadastro de Produto Woocommerce fora do painel Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um site em Wordpress onde estou utilizando o plugin Woocommerce para administração de produtos e etc.

Além disso, o site vai contar com vendedores onde os mesmos poderão registrar produtos em seus nomes(ou de suas lojas) mas que para a realização do cadastro dos produtos não podem ser feitos através do painel administrativo do Wordpress.

Preciso apresentar ao meu cliente uma forma do registro ser em alguma outra página, por exemplo, utilizando algum plugin ou não sei o que.

Procurei e não achei uma forma de fazer isso... utilizar o formulário de cadastro de produtos woocommerce que pode ser acessado fora do admin do wordpress, claro que o "vendedor" tem que estar logado para que acessar uma determinada página o cadastro de produtos seja habilitado.

Existe algum plugin? Algum shortcode? Ou vou ter que fazer isso na unha?

Se tiver que fazer isso na unha, alguém sabe uma solução de como é o comportamento de registro do Woocommerce no banco de dados?

Obrigado!

Comment: O Woocommerce tem uma [API](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/). Acredito que, se realmente você não pode criar *roles* de usuãrios com permissões customizadas para que eles entrem no painel e realizem o cadastro, você deve começar por aí.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode tentar integrar com o PMPro ou outro plugin de controle de nível de usuário. Busque por "Membership" plugins no WP, vai encontrar alguns.

Pode usar plugins que controlam quais menus aparecem pra quem está logado com definidas autorizações. O "if menu" é um deles, mas é bem simples.

Por fim pode usar o TML "Theme My Login" pra fazer uma página de login de acordo com o seu tema.

A partir daí vc estrutura o site conforme precisa.

Se não conseguir achar esses plugins me avisa que amanhã coloco os links pra vc aqui (to escrevendo do cel).

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Answer (score 0):

O Woocomerce possui uma API REST que consegue manipular todas as funções e atributos de toda a ferramenta.
Abaixo está exemplificado como cadastrar um produto em PHP utilizando a API REST do woocomerce.

```
<?php
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg',
            'position' => 0
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg',
            'position' => 1
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
?>
```

Link para a documentação: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product